# MongoDb Json Schema Validation Draft 4

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using Mongodb's oneOf validator using JSON schema validation. As far as I know MongoDb supports Draft 4 of Schema Validation and the validation rules I'm using appear as valid in [this online validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "foo": {},
      "bar": {}
    },
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "foo": {}
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
           "bar": {}
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    ]
}
```

Input document I'm passing is

```
{  
    "bar": {},
}
```

Why does it fail when I use the same schema validation in Mongo and pass in an object with attribute **foo** or attribute **bar**?

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      foo: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      },
      bar: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      }
    },
    oneOf: [
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          foo: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          bar: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      }
    ]
  }
}


db.dmt2.insert({"bar": ""})
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
```

Comment: Is the error code listed anywhere in the mongodb documentation?

Comment: The error code was code 121, which is the default error which is spat out. It is not very useful for debugging and had to resort to add field by field and testing that way which takes more time than necessary (in my opinion).

Comment: There's also a ticket (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20547) in Mongo's product development software which was created 4+ years ago. This doesn't seem to be solved in the near future...

Comment: Yikes. Thanks for the heads up. With JSON Schema 2019-09, we defined a standard set of output structures. I can understand their reluctancy to implement something which may or may not be useful. We have yet to open up discussions with MongoDB for JSON Schema =/

Comment: Sure, no probs! That's something which I will look at, thank you. Even if they allow the description field, it would probably save a lot of headaches (even the last comments were saying so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by specifying the *_id* and including it in both of the possible schemas of *oneOf*. I think when Mongo was adding a document it was inserting its default _id which wasn't part of the specified schema, and it started complaining.

I want to replicate the issue to re-confirm but as far as I remember that was the issue.